# Calibrating my room

Tags: room, calibration, monitor-calibration, monitoring

I was wondering what would be the best way to calibrate my room in my new apartment to my Mackie MR5's. The room is relatively small (10x12?) about 10 foot ceilings and carpeted with one window. I don't want to spend too much money since I'm not sure how long I'll be living there. So I just want to do the best I can for the least amount of money if possible. Thanks!

edit: Also I have my speakers stacked on top of books. Is it really worth the investment in speaker stands? And if so what are some cheap stands that will do?

Answer (score 3):

You say "calibrate" although you seem to be asking for help on deadening your room.

[This Sound on Sound article](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/mar02/articles/monitors.asp) is a good start, at least it got me going by prioritizing the factors and possible fixes to bad acoustics.

I once visited a guy's home studio in a much smaller room that what you describe. He had these home made clouds he built out of rockwool that he framed with wood and covered with fabric. He put one of these on each wall and on the ceiling.

Finally, fill your room with soft surfaces, hang things on the wall if you can, try to break any nasty right angle. Think about the sound waves' critical trajectories between the speakers, the walls and your ears, and break these paths as early as you can by putting soft/irregular surfaces and obstacles.

That's the philosophy at least...

Comment: @Justin Huss. I was referring to calibrating and thought deadening of the room kind of went along with the topic, but I guess I was mistaken haha. BTW are there any speaker stands you would suggest? Thanks for the advice. 

Comment: @Mitchell unfortunately I have no experience that I could share in monitors stands. I was looking for a pair a few months ago and I could get Samson ones for £50, don't know how sturdy they could be though (not in terms of weight support but rather of neutralisation of the vibrations...).

Answer (score 2):

Guide found here - http://www.dynamicinterference.com/2010/09/01/quick-and-dirty-monitor-calibration/

Comment: @Ade Thank you sir. I will try it out. Is there a certain SPL meter you use to calibrate your room?

Comment: For a budget I would recommend the Silverline Sound Level Meter, its pretty much the same as the Radioshack one in the tutorial above. Have a search on the net you will find it.